# Getting the selected item's position in Android popup menu class

Tags: java, android

I want to store some data into every item in a popup menu. All of the items are inflated programatically in a for loop based on results returned from a feed.

In the following example, I use a `HashMap` `storedOption` to store each item's data with the loop indices as keys. But I need to find a way to get the position of the selected item in `onMenuItemClick` so that I can retrieve the data from `storedOption`. Can anyone tell me how to do that? Besides the following attempt, I have also tried `item.getOrder()` but it always returns 0 regardless of how many items it has in the menu.

```
 public DynamicPopUpMenu{

    private Map<String,FeatureList> storedOption = new HashMap();

    public void main(final Context context,List<FeatureList> featureList){

        int count = 0;
        PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(context, featureList);
        for(FeatureList f:featureList) {
            MenuItem item = menu.getMenu().add(f.key);
            storedOption.put(count, f);
            count++;
        }

        menu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
               AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
                int position = info.position;
                new ShowToast(context,Integer.toString(position)); // show position in a toast
                return true;
            }
        });

        menu.show();
    }

  }
```

Comment: Whats this `value` in that `ShowToast` ?

Comment: try get `id = item.getItemId();` and setid to menuItem when you add in Popupmenu

Comment: @Shark.I have updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `featureList.key` as the key of your `storeOption` and them use `item.getItemId();` to get the value from `storeOption`.

Like this:

```
 public DynamicPopUpMenu{

    private Map<String,FeatureList> storedOption = new HashMap();

    public static void main(final Context context,List<FeatureList> featureList){

        int count = 0;
        PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(context, featureList);
        for(FeatureList f:featureList) {
            MenuItem item = menu.getMenu().add(f.key);
            storedOption.put(f.key, f);
            count++;
        }

        menu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
               AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
                int id = item.getItemId();
                FeatureList mFeatureList = (FeatureList)storedOption(id)
                new ShowToast(context,Integer.toString(value)); // show position in a toast
                return true;
            }
        });

        menu.show();
    }

  }
```